# Hyphenate wrap-around porch?

Tags: orthography, hyphenation

I do not know if it is correct to use a hyphen between the words wrap, and around, in describing a porch that wraps around a house.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The adjective "wraparound" does not have a hyphen in [Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wraparound), in case you're American, or Oxford English Dictionary [(free citation through Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/wraparound), in case you're British, those two tomes being generally accepted as the standard for AmE an BrE, respectively.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98246/discussion-on-answer-by-benjamin-harman-hyphenate-wrap-around-porch).

Comment: In the New Oxford Dictionary for Writers & Editors (one of their most compact dictionaries) 'wrap-around' does have a hyphen.